# Instantiating RInScala results in NoSuchMethodError

Tags: r, scala

I'm trying to integrate R into Scala using JVMR. I am getting a NoSuchMethodError when attempting to instantiate RInScala.

I'm working on a Windows 7 machine with R installed under C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.1 and Scala version 2.11.1 is installed under C:\Program Files (x86)\scala. I'm developing in IntelliJ with the Scala plugin and am using the Scala worksheet just to test this out as a POC. My Scala project does show JVMR 2.11-2.11.1.1.jar as an included library. The worksheet is very basic at present - just the import and the instantiation attempt.

```
import org.ddahl.jvmr.RInScala
val R = RInScala()
```

When running the worksheet in IntelliJ, I see the following output, so I can tell that it's successfully importing the class, but can't instantiate.

```
import org.ddahl.jvmr.RInScala
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.runtime.ObjectRef.create(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/runtime/ObjectRef;
at org.ddahl.jvmr.RInScala$.findROnWindows(RInScalaTest.sc2318647708135405919.tmp:804)
at org.ddahl.jvmr.RInScala$.defaultExecutable$lzycompute(RInScalaTest.sc2318647708135405919.tmp:822)
at org.ddahl.jvmr.RInScala$.defaultExecutable(RInScalaTest.sc2318647708135405919.tmp:821)
at org.ddahl.jvmr.RInScala.<init>(RInScalaTest.sc2318647708135405919.tmp:28)
at org.ddahl.jvmr.RInScala$.apply(RInScalaTest.sc2318647708135405919.tmp:838)
at com.xxxx.r_in_scala.A$A1$A$A1.R$lzycompute(RInScalaTest.sc2318647708135405919.tmp:2)
at com.xxxx.r_in_scala.A$A1$A$A1.R(RInScalaTest.sc2318647708135405919.tmp:2)
at com.xxxx.r_in_scala.A$A1$A$A1.get$$instance$$R(RInScalaTest.sc2318647708135405919.tmp:2)
at #worksheet#.#worksheet#(RInScalaTest.sc2318647708135405919.tmp:10)
```

I've drilled into the code for findROnWindows and my installation should be found based on the values of the registry keys that are being read. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but am at that "I've been looking at the problem for too long without figuring it out and just need a new set of eyes" stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge this is currently some kind of bug in the worksheet implementation by IntelliJ or indeed a misconfiguration. To verify:
Put your code in an object

```
package starter
object Test extends App {
  import org.ddahl.jvmr.RInScala
  val R = RInScala()
  println("works")
}
```

and try to run it as a scala app and not from the worksheet.